# access data or this attribute in ajax beforeSend function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get a value from my data array in the `beforeSend` function, but when I try to display it in the console all I see is `undefined`.

I tried printing the `$(this)` variable which also returns `undefined`.

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var data = {
        "action": $(this).attr("id")
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type:  $(this).attr("method"),
      dataType: $(this).data("type"),
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function(data) {
        console.log(data["action"]);
        console.log($(this).attr("method"));
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

How can I read the values stored in the data array in the `beforeSend` function

Comment: `$(this)` inside ajax refers to the ajax object not the form!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Agreed with @jmmontero in that you need to make a reference variable to `$(this)` before you go inside your `$ajax` function. The dupe is why this happens.

Comment: cheers jmmontero thats why I tried data['action'] to try and read a field from the data array

Comment: `data['action']` is undefined too because you serialized `data` into a string just before the ajax call.

Comment: thanks for all your help folks got it sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly, simply:

`this.data` .

This is serialize String, and then You can do whatever by string parsing/editing.

For example use:

`alert(this.data);`

for display serialized string.